# Webpage hosting is not working with xampp

Tags: hosting, html

Recently I tried to host a simple webpage using xampp. It was working before. Then later I tried some php form handling but it didn't work. Now, that simple web page hosting is not even working. I reinstalled the xampp and did the relevant changes but still its not working.
A little help ll be appreciated.
What I did is here in this word file.

I installed the xampp. So to make the `apache` working I made some changes as suggested by one person.

- Stopped every service in xampp
- Now, I clicked on config and open the httpd.config
- In between I change "listen" to `8080` instead of `80`
- Down i changed the `servername` local host to `8080` instead of `80`
- Closed the httpd.config file.
- Now I opened the `httpd-ssl.config` file and search to `Listen`
- Change the port to `4433` from `443`
- Down below I did this `<VirtualHost _default_:4433>`
- and, closed it.

Now, i have a HTML page in one directory, i kept it single page.
- Now, i open notepad using the admin.
- Browse to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` and open the `httpd-vhosts` file
- Uncomment this `ameVirtualHost *:8080` and make relevant changes as 8080 from 80.

Below I add this code :-

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "G:\HTML\proj1"
ServerName testing.com
   <Directory "G:\HTML\proj1">
        Require all granted
   </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

- Saved the file.
- Now again browse to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and open `hosts.conf file`
- And, add this line below `127.0.0.1       testing.com`
- Now closed the notepad after saving.
- I made a simple html page in the given directory `proj1`
- When i typed the testing.com in browser nothing happened. And, yeah I did started the apache also.